# Issues with scheduleAtFixedRate()

Tags: java, timer, schedule

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
public class SecondsTimer{
     private ScheduledExecutorService timer;
     private int seconds=0;
     public SecondsTimer(){
          long second=1000;
          timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable(){public void run(){seconds++;}},
                                    second, second, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
     }
     public int getSeconds(){return seconds;}
}
```

In the above code, I am attempting to create code to count seconds as they pass. I'm getting a runtime error, `NullPointerException` for line 9. Is there an easier way to do this, or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you never set the variable `timer`, so it is `null` when you try to use it.

For guidance on how to instantiate the `ScheduledExecutorService` Interface, [have a look at the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

You would have to set it before line 9, thus before you try to access it.

---

Side note: since you are working with multiple threads that all write-access one variable, you should also [look into the concept of thread safety](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076747/core-java/design-for-thread-safety.html).